# PlayerDecision Trouble

Tags: java

I am trying to write up a game of rock-paper-scissors, and I think I am almost done. However, I am having trouble calling one last method.
This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RPS {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      PlayerChoice();
      ComputerChoice();
      System.out.println("You played " + playerDecision + ". The computer played " + computerPlay +".");
   }
   public static void PlayerChoice() {
      System.out.print("Type R(ock), P(aper) or S(cissors): ");
      int r = "rock";
      int p = "paper";
      int s = "scissors";
      String r = console.r();
      string p = console.p();
      String s = console.s();
      Random rand = new Random();
      int playerDecision = nextInt();
         if(playerDecision.equalsIgnoreCase("r")){
            System.out.println("rock");
         }else if(playerDecision.equalsIgnoreCase("p")){
            System.out.println("paper");
         }else if(playerDecision.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
            System.out.println("scissors");
         }
         while(!nextInt = 'r' || 'p' || 's'){
            System.out.println("Invalid answer. Re-type R, P or S: ");
         }
         System.out.print(playerDecision);
   }  
   public static void ComputerChoice() {
      int rock = 1, paper = 2, scissors = 3;
      Random rand = new Random();
      int computerPlay = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;

      if(computerPlay == 0){
         System.out.println("rock");
      }else if(computerPlay == 1){
         System.out.println("paper");
      }else if(computerPlay == 2){
         System.out.println("scissors");
      }
      System.out.print(computerPlay);
   }
}
```

However, my code cannot find the playerDecision or computerPlay. I want the method PlayerChoice to put out the players decision, as stated in its name. If they put in "R", register rock, "P" for paper, and "S" for scissors, regardless of case. The ComputerChoice method seems to be working fine.
Does anybody know what am I doing wrong while calling the decisions? I do not know why it won't read right, and I am out of ideas.
Does anybody have a suggestion for me?

Comment: 1. You misspelled `String` 2. `playerDecision`, `computerPlay` or `nextInt`  are never defined (computerPlay and playerDecision are only available in the methods they are defined, you will either want to `return` the value or use instance variables. You may be looking to use a `Scanner` for nextInt, though I have no idea what you're doing) 3. As noted in an answer, your logic is wrong.

Comment: Well thanks for pointing out the String spelling mistake... That would have been embarrassing to turn in. I didn't even notice that at all.

Comment: @Zachary You are right. I sort of defined those, but nextInt is defined within playerDecision, and the other two are not fully defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "short-cut" syntax is illegal. And your logic is a bit off. `while(!nextInt = 'r' || 'p' || 's'){` should be something like

```
while (nextInt != 'r' && nextInt != 'p' && nextInt != 's') {
```

**or** apply DeMorgan's Laws, and get

```
while (!(nextInt == 'r' || nextInt == 'p' || nextInt == 's')) {
```

Also, `ComputerChoice` is **not** "working fine". You are generating values in the range 1 to 3 (inclusive), but you are only checking zero, one and two. Remove the `+ 1` in `int computerPlay = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;` (or fix the if logic).

Comment: Ok. I thought I had edited the random values, but I must have missed that. I will check those &&/|| values. Thanks.

Comment: Well those all seemed to have worked out, but my main method call still put out the "can't find symbol" errors for the playerChoice and computerChoice calls. Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: "Can't find symbol" is usually a misspelled variable or method name.

Comment: Well those are spelled right. I think it has to do with the fact that they are in the other methods, but I thought that would be taken care of by calling those methods into main. I guess I need to find a way to put those into that first statement, don't I?

Comment: @markspace Check your *capitalization*. You can't name it `PlayerChoice`, and then call it like `playerChoice`.

Comment: Well, thanks to everybody that helped out. I couldn't quite get it all to work, but I should at least be able to get most of the possible credit for this. I appreciate you fellows pointing out my errors.